# Question in reopen queue edit contains answer

Tags: discussion, review, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

Please see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024157/message-related-event-handling-in-blackberry-10

This question is currently on hold.

However, an edit was made to it which put it into the Reopen queue. This edit was made by another user, posting the answer into the question, specifically because the question was closed so he couldn't post the answer the normal way.

I suspect the question will be reopened, but what to do about the answer that's been posted into the question? Can that be moved into a proper answer by a mod?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should edit the answer out of the question.  (I have rolled back the edit for this particular question.)  Questions are for asking the question, not posting answers.  Answers should be posted as answers.  If a question is closed and you would like to post an answer to it, then first ensure that the post has addressed the issues that caused it to be closed, then get it reopened, then post the answer.  Putting the answer in the question is not appropriate, even for a closed question.